# How can I redirect multiple variants to the same URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using match in rails routing, as:

```
match "/about/" => about#index
```

both mysite.com/about/ and mysite.com/about show the same page.
This may create some duplicate content issues.
What I what to accomplish is that mysite.com/about will be directed to the other URL varient, i.e. mysite.com/about/.

I tried to accomplish simple by writing:

```
match "/about" => "/about"
```

but this cause a major error in my routing file and the application failed.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following line in application.rb to generate a tailing slash for all the url

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

Comment: Should this go inside the `class Application < Rails::Application`?

Comment: This works find, however when using `<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>` the output is //, which is a broken link. How can I fix this?

Comment: How is root configured in routes.rb?